# Android Version and API confirmation

Tags: android

I am new in Android Development and I want to ask a question that
In Android SDK packages are listed as 
SDK platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 1

Can Anyone explain me what is meant by  Android 2.3.3 and API 10 and  revision 1 particularly.

It will help to understand the basic concept clearly

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android 2.3.3** is the Android Platform Version Name

**Android 2.3.3** belongs to the Android **API10**  (API Level) wich identifies the framework API revision offered by a version of the Android Platform. **API10** includes Android Platforms version **2.3.3**-**2.3.7**

Releases of the SDK Tools are denoted by revision number, in each revision you can note some added tools, caching and performance improvement and [more](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html).

Answer (score 3):

- API 10 is the API level.
- Android 2.3.3 => Version Name
- revision 1 => serial number of the particular revision of SDK.

> **What is API Level?**
>
> API Level is an integer value that uniquely identifies the framework API revision offered by a version of the
> Android platform.
> Read more: [What is API Level?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) and [Uses of API Level in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#uses)

You can read more about here => [Platform Versions](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)